# Print template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am trying to create a template vector of arbitrary number of int parameters and create a function to print those parameters:

```
namespace ex {

    template <int I, class... Ts>
    constexpr decltype(auto) get(Ts&& ... ts) {
        return std::get<I>(std::forward_as_tuple(ts...));
    }

    template<int... N>
    struct vec
    {
        static const int size = sizeof...(N);
        void print() {
            print(size-1);
        }

        void print(const int n) {
            if (n >= 0) {
                print(n - 1);
                std::cout << ex::get<n>(N...) << std::endl;
            }
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    ex::vec<1, 2, 3> v;
    v.print();
}
```

And I got the following errors:

```
error C2672: 'ex::get': no matching overloaded function found
error C2975: 'I': invalid template argument for 'ex::get', expected compile-time constant expression
```

Can anyone please explain that am I missing and how to achieve the behaviour I expect?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to C++17, you can benefit from [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template<int... N>
struct vec {
    void print() {
        ((std::cout << N << std::endl), ...);
    }
};
```

Before C++17, you can use dummy array initialization trick:

```
template<int... N>
struct vec {
    void print() {
        int dummy[]{0, ((std::cout << N << std::endl), 0)...};
        (void)dummy;
    }
};
```

The first zero is there to handle empty `N...` packs. The second zero is a part of a [comma operator expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). The order of evaluation of arguments in a braced list is fixed by their order in that list [[dcl.init.list/4]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#4).

---

> But what if I want to operate on the individual parameter, for instance, I want to add `operator+` which adds 2 vectors. For instance adding `vec<1,2,3> v1` and `vec<4,5> v2` will result a `vec<5,7,3> v3`?

If packs can have different sizes, some tricks are needed. For example:

```
template<std::size_t... S, int... N, int... M>
auto add_impl(vec<N...>, vec<M...>, std::index_sequence<S...>)
{
    constexpr int is1[sizeof...(S)]{N...};
    constexpr int is2[sizeof...(S)]{M...};
    return vec<(is1[S] + is2[S])...>{};
}

template<int... N, int... M>
auto operator+(vec<N...> v1, vec<M...> v2) {
    constexpr auto size = std::max(sizeof...(N), sizeof...(M));
    return add_impl(v1, v2, std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
}
```

Comment: thanks this seals the deal in case of print.
But what if I wans to operate on the individual parameter, for instance, I want to add operator + wich adds 2 vectors. For instance adding vec<1,2,3> v1 and vec<4,5> v2 will result a vec<5,7,3> v3?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan, if packs have the same size, it is pretty easy: https://godbolt.org/z/or7scM. If they don't have the same size, some tricks are needed.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan, one possible trick: https://godbolt.org/z/evWYEa